# Variable scope when using $http service in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm hoping someone can shed some light on the scope of variables when using the $http AngularJS service.

My code looks like this:

```
app.controller('TestPlanRequestCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.tableData = [];  // Populate the table with this array
    $scope.tpRequests = null;
    $http.get('common/data/requests.json').success(function(data) {
        $scope.tpRequests = data.TPRequests;
    });
```

Next I want to run a loop to put my data into an array like so:

```
for (var i = 0; i < $scope.tpRequests.length; ++i) {
        var requestObj= {
            requestNum: $scope.tpRequests[i].RequestNumber;
        }
        $scope.tableData.push(requestObj);
}
```

This works great if the for loop is inside the function called from the success method, but I think it would be cleaner to keep it outside the call.  If I have the loop outside the call, I get the error:

`Error: $scope.tpRequests is null`

I don't understand why tpRequests is populated in the get call, and then the data is gone after the get call ends.  I'm guessing it is considering the $scope.tpRequests inside the function call to be a different one than the one I declared above the $http.get().  What's the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `$watch` on `$scope.tpRequests` to do your data manipulation, however I would recommend just doing it in the success promise if there are no other ways to trigger the watch and simply check for `null`/`undefined` before operating.

A great primer on use cases for `$watch` and `$watchCollection`:
http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2566-scope-watch-vs-watchcollection-in-angularjs.htm